# Convert the Regular expression to used in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Please guide me to covert this regular expression

```
“A - Z”, “a - z”,”0 - 9” and “-, _/, \”.
```

to use in javascript

Comment: regex is a javascript feature.... it has nothing to do with jQuery

Comment: what are you trying to do

Comment: i need to check the text box that may contain “A - Z”, “a - z”,”0 - 9” and “-, _/, \”.

Comment: Just use the part inside the quotes and lookup how to instantiate a regex in Javascript.

Comment: ti shoule be `var rg = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_[\]\\/]*$");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the regex between slashes: `var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_[\]\\/]*$/;`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var rg = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_[\\]\\/]*$");
```

or

```
var rg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-_[\]\/]*$/;
```

there is no type reference in javascript, all variables will be declared using `var` and the regex type is `RegExp`